# Error- Validate Multiple APi call response in one scenario in karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to use two api call (Post & put call) in one scenario in karate framework. But I am not able to validate 2nd Api call response. when i tried to do like response.id , it passing 1 st api call response.

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Can you share some code ? it will be easy for us to identify exact problem. As per document `response` always get [overridden](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#response) when new request is made to api.

Comment: @k33da_the_bug - i have added my feature file , could you please share your ideas

Answer (score 1):

In your feature file, you wrote your `print response` in `When` instead of writing it after `Then`. Which means it is showing the previous response only. As per documentation response gets [overridden](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#response) after making a new http request.

Following,

```
...
When method put
And print 'jokerresult-->',response.joker_result
Then status 201
```

Should be like,

```
...
When method put
Then status 201
And print 'jokerresult-->',response.joker_result
```

let me know if it worked for you or not.